# Layout help with custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm playing around with 2D drawing within a custom view. So far I've got it drawing what I want(Point data from an array) but I want the drawing to scale and be able to extend it beyond the screen(such that 1 second of data per screen width). The method I'm using for drawing relies on `getHeight` and `getWidth` to set the bounds of the information in the screen. I'm using the screens width to extend the canvas in `onDraw` to several screen widths in size(depending on the time of the data).

I've been unable to find a way of drawing that will allow me to scroll horizontally, and support a zoom like function... is there an easy way of doing this? ScrollView doesn't do Horizontally, and when I go beyond the screen it just get's cut off. My layout so far is

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
            <view class="com.box.sand.SandGraph$GraphView"
                android:id="@+id/graph"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

But when I put this in, the onDraw of my view never get's called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This may solve your problem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Although I doubt that it has a zoom function, you should be able to implement the rest of what you're asking for using this.

EDIT:

The hierarchy would go as follows:

```
<HorizontalScrollView ... >
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Content goes here />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I had attempted to use this and it wouldn't display anything, the `getHeight` within my view that was wrapped in this was 0. But I will delve deeper into this Class.

Comment: You need to make sure the LinearLayout that you're using as the single child is set to android:orientation="horizontal".  Also, make sure you're using a single layout for the child of this view.

Comment: So would I wrap my view in a HorizontalScrollView, then that HSV in a LinearLayout?

Comment: Tried what you suggested and the onDraw of my View never even get's called.

Comment: are you calling the supermethod for all of your overridden methods? that could be the problem.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2371/discussion-between-nicholas-and-pheonixblade9)